# JavaScript/regex: Remove text between brackets in string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How would I remove all <> tags from a string, and the contents within them?

`<p>Hello, how are you doing <strong>today</strong></p>`

to

`Hello, how are you doing today`

using JavaScript with Regex?

Comment: `"<p>Hello, how are you doing <strong>today</strong></p>".replace(/\<[^>]+\>/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```js
const input = '<p>Hello, how are you doing <strong>today</strong></p>';

const result = input.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Sorry Regex really confuses me with all the random symbols crammed together.

Comment: I suggest you use https://regex101.com which explains and helps debug regexes